# How do I get the zoom percentage toolbar in Adobe Acrobat Reader?

Tags: adobe-reader

Using Adobe Acrobat Reader, I wonder where is the zoom tool on the horizontal toolbar, where it was possible to set percentage of the zoom? It was there yesterday, and now suddenly it disappeared! I didn't update the app, don't know what happened.... This is annoying....

[image]

**EDIT:** Unfortunatelly, it's strange but I don't have a "Zoom level" tool there! :-/

[image]

Here is the version information:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**A)** If your Acrobat is correctly working, then use this first step. Otherwise, go to B)

- Right-click on the toolbar (next to the various symbols).
- Hover on `Show Select & Zoom Tools`
- Select the functions you need. I think you intend the `Zoom level` tool

[image]

**B)** Reboot your machine, restart acrobat.

- navigate to the Preferences from Edit>Preferences>General> select 'Open documents as new tabs in the same Window'>Click OK.
- Restart the application and check.

**C)** If this doesn't work, you need to reset your preferences to default:

- Quit Acrobat.
- In Windows Explorer, go to the Preferences folder:(Windows 10, 7/Vista) C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Acrobat[version]
- Move the Preferences folder to another location (for example, C:\Temp).
- Restart Acrobat.

SOURCES:

- [Adobe Support Community - thread 1 (solution B)](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader-discussions/zoom-options-are-missing-from-page-control-menu/td-p/10195717)
- [Adobe Support Community - thread 2 (solution C)](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/how-to-reset-acrobat-preference-settings-to-default/td-p/4792082)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatelly, I cannot find the "Zoom level" tool - see the update of my question...

Comment: @Tomas in my updated answer, B) or C) should work

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on the horizontal toolbar.
2. Select Show Selct & Zoom Tools -> Zoom Level.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatelly, I cannot find the "Zoom level" tool - see the update of my question...

Comment: @Tomas We have the same version. Do you see when you go to View -> Show/Hide -> Toolbar Items -> Show Select & Zoom Tools -> Zoom Level? You can also press Alt+F8 to reset the toolbar. OR click on Show All Select & Zoom Tools to check if it will reappear.

Comment: 1) no I don't 2) **Alt-F8 worked, thanks!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. But Alt+F8 didn't work for me because stupid GeForce Experience hijacked that shortcut and I was too lazy to go dig out how to resolve that. Eventually I found its the "Zoom To" function in the (View -> Zoom -> Zoom To) Acrobat Reader. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Just "reset" your tool bar by right clicking the toolbar and hitting "Reset Toolbar" at the bottom of the menu that pops open.

Comment: No need to disparage while answering.